# Two notifications for empathy and no notification preferences tab?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, empathy, notification

I am getting an issue with empathy.

When I am in a chat every time I send a message I get a standard gnome-shell notification echoing what I just set, the same applies for when a message is received.
After this notification disappears a second one pops up, being the empathy notification that allows me to reply.

After doing some Google searches I am being told to disable the bubble notifications in the empathy Preferences under Notifications.

Issue being, I don't have a Notifications tab.

What's up with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having this problem too since I switched to GNOME Shell on Ubuntu 12.04, and I tried Gevorg's solution but it didn't work.

Looking more closely at the file, I can see why: It turns off notifications for a bunch of things, but not for incoming messages.

Follow his instructions, but add the following line in between the gconf tags:

```
<entry name="notifications_message_received" mtime="1334850046" type="bool" value="false">
```

Also, don't use sudo to copy it in there or you'll screw up your permissions. Best to save the file, create the directories while you're doing that (right-click on the save file dialog to show hidden files, go into .gconf, go into apps, go into empathy, right-click to create new directory, call it notifications, go in there and save it).

After you've done that, you'll only get one notification on each incoming message, and it'll be the one that lets you reply inside of it. I.e. the right kind for GNOME Shell.

Has anyone filed a bug report about this? This behavior is pretty annoying.

Comment: Actually, this got it working last night but now today it's not working anymore ... I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

## How to change Notification settings in Empathy without GUI

Open terminal and type

```
sudo vim ~/.gconf/apps/empathy/notifications/%gconf.xml
```

or

```
sudo gedit ~/.gconf/apps/empathy/notifications/%gconf.xml
```

and replace all `true`-s to `false`

## If notifications folder does not exist

create folder in **~/.gconf/apps/empathy/** called **notifications**, then download [this](http://ubuntuone.com/0sE5igCO8pahPQShniFECO)(right click, save link as), copy **%gconf.xml** to **~/.gconf/apps/empathy/notifications**
the tab will apear

Comment: The file does not exist. actually. the notifications folder does not exist..

Comment: @Hailwood did the folder ~/.gconf/apps/empathy/ exist??

Comment: Yeah. The folder did. And it has stuff in it. Just no notification folder

Comment: @Hailwood look at the edit

Comment: Followed the instructions, still no notifications folder :(

Comment: in my edit i say that you must create a folder @Hailwood

Comment: Sorry,  that was a typo. I did create the folder.  Meant still no tab.

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem. It seems to be a noisy bug in some infrastructure packages. Like the notification tab in empathy, some other apps also miss some widgets in their UI.

You've to edit the dconf manually.

First, install dconf-editor (I don't know the package name 'cause i'm using fedora 17).

Second, find the preferences in org/gnome/empathy/notifications

Third, set "notifications-enabled" to false.

Comment: This is the easiest way to do it. The problem seems to be that Empathy is sending notifications via the usual method, but Shell doesn't need that - it intervenes in the Telepathy channels, which is how it offers inline reply functionality. So turning off Empathy notifications leaves you with just Shell's popups and no more annoying duplicates.